# Stop click event propagation of all children

Tags: javascript, angular

How to stop the `click` event propagation of all children elements:

```
<div (click)="openModal()">
    <span>Click in this element open the modal</span>
    <li>Click in this element open the modal too</li>
    <p>Click in this element open the modal too</p>
    <input type="button">Click in this element open the modal too</input>
</div>
```

I want to open the modal only with the `div` element. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to conditionally execute logic *only* when the parent `div` element is clicked (and not when the event propagates when clicking on a child element), then you could check to see if the event's [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is equal to the [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

- The [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) always refers to the element that the event is bound to. In this case, the `(click)` event is bound to the `div` element.
- The [`event.target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) always refers to the element that dispatched the event.

Therefore, if you only want to filter out instances where a child element is clicked and you want to essentially filter out propagated events, then you can check to see if `$event.currentTarget` is equal to `$event.target`:

```
public openModal ($event) {
  if ($event.currentTarget === $event.target) {
    // Clicked on the parent `div` element with the
    // click event binding `(click)="openModal($event)"`
    console.log('Clicked the parent, not the child.');
  }
}
```

```
<div (click)="openModal($event)">
  <span>...</span>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```